# Allow a user can see stored procedures created by others users

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, sql-grant, stored-functions

I have a MySQL database with some stored procedures. The problem is that there are two different users who created several procedures, so that just the user who created the stored procedure can see your content. Within this context, I want all the two users could see all stored procedures, in other words, those created by him and another user.

How this could be possible?

Answer (score 2):

To allow multiple Users access to others Stored Procs you should use the GRANT statement as follows.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.myproc TO 'userx'@'localhost';
```

You can find more details [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
GRANT Execute  ON `db_name`.* TO `user_1`@`localhost`;
GRANT Execute  ON `db_name`.* TO `user_2`@`localhost`;
```

Comment: I just try: GRANT EXECUTE ON database.* TO 'user'@'%'; but doesn't worked for me.

Comment: your SQL looks correct but are you running as "root" or user ?

Comment: I'm not running this grant as root, but as other or same user who had permissions.